# Getting compiler Error for Typescript for the newly added file

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I am getting the following Error

Error   TS2307  Cannot find module '@angular/core'. TypeScript Virtual Projects c:\XXXXXXXXXXXX\angularapp\app\employer\list\component\employer.list.component.ts
This Error is reported in the Visual Studio 2015 IDE, my Web Pack compiles and rlaunches website successfully on port 8080.

The reason i want to get rid of this is that we are using TFS and Gated checkin which prevents code checkin if the build fails.

I am not getting any error for some of the about & home modules.

What could i be missing

Answer (score 0):

you need to post your tsconfig and package json files.  Ensure there is a node_modules/@angular/core.  if not, and json configurations are correct, run npm install.